# Output different words from two different files in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I have two files one with a text full of mistakes, capital letters and punctuation and another one containing all the words in the dictionary. I need to output all the misspelled words into a new file.

I tried the diff , comm and cmp, grep and vim but it keeps returning the wrong output.

Let's say file text contains :

```
A discreption of a task to do.
```

and the dictionary contains :

```
a
description 
of
task
to
do
```

the output of the mistake should be the word discreption and maybe even the word do. since it has a dot at the end.

Comment: Please provide samples a solution could be tested against.

Comment: if you want to use `comm` you'll need to *a)* insure both files contain data with the same capitalization (eg, everything is lowercase), *b)* insure each word from `text` is on its own line, *c)* eliminate extraneous white space (after placing words on their own line) punctuation characters and non-printing characters, and probably special characters (eg, | % $ @ # ^ ( ) [ ], etc); one common tool for removing characters and capitalization is `tr`

Comment: @pmf I did provide a sample of both files and the output im expecting

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks for the tip, i added the line of commands to put everything in lowercase and on a different line too.

Comment: ok, that's a start, though reading/writing from `textlowercase` in the same command could be problematic (best to use a different file for the output, especially when dealing with larger files);  you then need to remove everything but letters (and digits?) from the modified contents of `text`, sort and then `comm` against (a sorted version of) dictionary; there may be a need to do some tweaking afterwards but that should get you most of the way to the desired output

Comment: This has nothing to de with terminals (the script would behave the same way run completely "headless" with no terminal present); removing the terminal tag. (I'm also a little wary of the diff/cmp/comm tags insofar as they feel like spamming tools you think someone _could possibly_ use in an answer, vs being tools your question is about; better to just tag "unix" if you want answers using standard UNIX tools).

Comment: @markp-fuso thanks to you i found the answer ! I updated my post with the correct answer since i imagine other people will be looking for it in the future. Thank you

Comment: keep in mind that this gets you a workable solution but it's not necessarily efficient; if you're working with relatively small files and/or not doing this very often then performance probably isn't very important; if performance becomes an issue then you'll want to look at other solutions that reduce the number of steps (aka subprocesses) which could include solutions based on `awk`, `perl`, `ruby`, `python`, etc

Answer (score 2):

If "word" can be interpreted as a sequence of letters contained in the range from `a` to `z`, you could use `grep -Eo '[a-z]+'` to do the word splitting. Then, find the lines contained in the (prepared) text file but not in the (prepared) dict file.

Here's an example using `comm -13`, showing only the second column, i.e. lines contained in the second input, but not in the first:

```bash
comm -13 \
  <(sort -u dict.txt) \
  <(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < text.txt | grep -Eo '[a-z]+' | sort -u)
```

Here's another one using `grep -Fxvf`, showing lines from the second input that are not found in the first input, which is interpreted as a list of full-line fixed strings (not regular expressions):

```bash
grep -Fxvf \
  <(sort -u dict.txt) \
  <(tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < text.txt | grep -Eo '[a-z]+' | sort -u)
```

For the sample inputs given, both output:

```
discreption
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an awk to do what you describe:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{dict[$1]; next}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        word=tolower($i)
        gsub(/[^a-z]/, "", word)
        if (word in dict) continue
        print word
    }
}
' dict.txt text.txt
```

Or a `ruby`:

```
ruby -e 'dict=File.open(ARGV[0]).read.split(/\R+/).map(&:strip).to_set
words=File.open(ARGV[1]).read.downcase.split(/[^a-zA-Z]+/).to_set
puts words.difference(dict).join("\n")
' dict.txt text.txt
```

Either prints:

```
discreption
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='[^[:alpha:]]+' '
    { $0 = tolower($0) }
    NR == FNR { dict[$0]; next }
    !($0 in dict)
' dict text
discreption
```

or any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk -v FS='[^[:alpha:]]+' '
    { $0 = tolower($0) }
    NR == FNR { dict[$0]; next }
    { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ( $i && !($i in dict) ) print $i }
' dict text
discreption
```